# How to create my own sleep or delay function in c

Tags: c, operating-system, timedelay

I'm creating a small kernel in C and I need a function that will take a parameter containing the amount of seconds it should wait for.

I've tried using for loops, but they haven't worked.

I can't use the C standard library and need a way to tell the kernel to wait(in C). How can I do this?

Loop:

```
int c = 1, d = 1;

for ( c = 1 ; c <= 32767 ; c++ )
    for ( d = 1 ; d <= 32767 ; d++ ){}
```

Comment: Share the code using loop. What didn't work?

Comment: The for loop works, but it's too fast to make any difference. @AT-2016

Comment: I am not sure if this helps you. But it seems really interesting - http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly

Comment: I was just looking up delay assembly function and using it with asm function. Let me know if you see a good, case-specific tutorial

Comment: Hope helps - http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/precise-clock-cycle-delay-inline-asm

Comment: "*How can I do this?*" If for *one* specific MC board, go for the loops as per the code you should, take out a stop watch and measure. If for multiply MCs have a look at their specific assembler instructions and timer support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a loop works, but the time it takes will be highly dependent on the speed of your CPU and any compiler optimisations. It's useful when you know the target hardware (e.g. writing for specific microcontroller).

You should include a NOP in the body of loop. Also check if your compiler supports a #pragma or special comment to disable optimisations on specific blocks of code.

Check your compiler documentation for a definition of NOP. Most compilers define a macro named `_nop()` or `_nop_()`

You can define your own using:

```
#define Nop() {_asm nop _endasm}
```

Or by writing `asm("nop")` if your compiler supports inline assembly.

Comment: "*specific microcontroller*": The only answer which make sense here.